# Django, caracteres especiais para HTML com um conteúdo salvo no banco de dados

Tags: html5, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Bom dia,

Estou com um conteúdo salvo no banco de dados em HTML:

**Campo: content**

```
<p><img src="/media/django-summernote/2019-08-26/2ed93bb9-8293-4b98-9ccb-eeba931421b5.png" style="width: 255px; float: left;" class="note-float-left">Na área de marketing, uma conversão ocorre quando o cliente realiza uma ação desejada. Podendo ser: assinar uma newsletter, fazer o download de um folheto ou fazer uma compra.</p>
```

Quando tento Exibir no template é adicionado caracteres especiais para HTML

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;/media/django-summernote/2019-08-26/2ed93bb9-8293-4b98-9ccb-eeba931421b5.png&quot; style=&quot;width: 255px; float: left;&quot; class=&quot;note-float-left&quot;&gt;Na área de marketing, uma conversão ocorre quando o cliente realiza uma ação desejada. Podendo ser: assinar uma newsletter, fazer o download de um folheto ou fazer uma compra.&lt;/p&gt;
```

Estou usando Visualizações genéricas DetailView para alimentar o template

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'blog\detalhes.html'
```

E no template:

```
<p class="text-gray-500">{{post.content}}</p>
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localizei a resposta,

O escape HTML está ativado por padrão nos modelos do Django.

```
{% autoescape off %}
<p class="text-gray-500">{{post.content}}</p>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Isso Resolveu o problema!

Caso alguém mais passe por isso